# SBS2011 - exchange 2010 - NEw mailbox accounts not showing in list of pop3 connector

Tags: exchange, pop3, windows-sbs-2011

I have migrated a SBS2003 --> SBS2011 and configured the pop3 connector for all the migrated mailboxes, which works fine. But when I create any new accounts, they are not listed as available accounts to retrieve pop3 email for. I cannot see them in the list.

Can anyway pont me in the right direction.

thanks

Comment: Are you adding the accounts via the "supported" management interface or are you adding them "by hand" using the "full blown" Active Directory and Exchange management tools?

Comment: thanks that answered my qeustion. Seems as if it only works if one adds accounts via the supported management interface.

Comment: I do not find the Attribute Editor. I found a trick to solve that here:
[thread at technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2008/09/22/why-are-some-of-my-users-not-displaying-in-the-sbs-console.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the SBS management tools to add the user accounts or they won't be visible in the POP3 Connector UI. In general you want to use the SBS tools and eschew the "full blown" AD and Exchange management tools (distasteful as that may sound).

Answer (score 2):

I found this somewhere and it worked for me:

> SBS won’t see users via the SBS Console or the POP3 Connector until you modify an attribute on the user object in AD.
>
> In AD, go to View -> Advanced Features. Then open up the user you want and go to the Attribute Editor tab. Find the property `msSBSCreationState`. Change the value to `Created`.
>
> Then your user will show up in the SBS Console and, if the account is mail enabled, the mailbox will show up in the drop-down list under the POP3 Connector as a valid Small Business Server email account.